# recursive function returns the same value each time

Tags: javascript

So I have a checkers game, and I am trying to get it so that you can jump over multiple spaces. It works if you jump the max amount of spaces, but if you don't, say you can jump over two spaces, and you choose to jump over only one, it still removes both pieces even though you only jumped over one of the pieces.  I think the problem has is inside the checkForJump() function, and it seems like every time the function is called, it returns the same array, any help would be appreciated.

```
 function checkForJump(buttonSelected, remove, isRoot) {

if(isRoot)
{
    clearAvailableMoves();
    switchPiece();
}
let adjacentValue = 0;
let jumpNotValid = false;
let RemoveTiles = remove;
for (let i = 0; i < adjacentTileValues.length; i++) {
  adjacentValue = adjacentTileValues[i];

  if (board.value[adjacentValue + buttonSelected] == enemyPiece && board.value[buttonSelected + (adjacentValue * 2)] == empty) {
    if (isSpaceAlreadyInArray(buttonSelected + adjacentValue * 2, i) == false) {

      RemoveTiles.push(buttonSelected + adjacentValue);

      let tile = new jumpTile(buttonSelected + (adjacentValue * 2));

      RemoveTiles.push(buttonSelected + adjacentValue);
      console.log("removeTiles" + RemoveTiles);

      for (let k = 0; k < RemoveTiles.length; k++) {
        tile.tilesToRemove.push(RemoveTiles[k]);
      }
      console.log("tile.tilesToRemove: " + tile.tilesToRemove);
      availableSpaces[i].push(tile);



      checkForJump(buttonSelected + (adjacentValue * 2), RemoveTiles,false);
      console.log("available spaces = " + availableSpaces);
    }
  }


}


  };
```

Here is some of the other code, relating to that could also be the source of the problem

```
    function jumpTile(tileID) {
      this.tilesToRemove = [];
      this.tileID = tileID;
       };


 let numBlackPieces = 12;
 let numWhitePieces = 12;


let adjacentTileValues = [7, 9, -7, -9];
 let availableSpaces = [
  [],
  [],
  [],
  []
    ];



  function checkValidSpace(buttonPressed, piece) {
 // if button is adjacent to selectedbutton
if (buttonPressed == selectedButton + 7 || buttonPressed == selectedButton + 9 || buttonPressed == selectedButton - 9 || buttonPressed == selectedButton - 7) {
  return true;
} else {
  let valid = false;
  // checks if there is a valid jump
  checkForJump(selectedButton,[],true);
  // foreach of the possible tiles, if the button pressed is one of them than remove all pieces in that tiles remove list
  for (let i = 0; i < availableSpaces.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < availableSpaces[i].length; j++) {
      if (buttonPressed == availableSpaces[i][j].tileID) {
        valid = true;
        console.log("availableSpaces[" + i + j + "]  is " + availableSpaces[i][j].tileID + "");
        remove(availableSpaces[i][j].tilesToRemove);

        return true;
      }
    }

  }
  if (valid == false)
    return false;



}


   }





  function checkForJump(buttonSelected, remove, isRoot) {

if(isRoot)
{
    clearAvailableMoves();
    switchPiece();
}
let adjacentValue = 0;
let jumpNotValid = false;
let RemoveTiles = remove;
for (let i = 0; i < adjacentTileValues.length; i++) {
  adjacentValue = adjacentTileValues[i];

  if (board.value[adjacentValue + buttonSelected] == enemyPiece && board.value[buttonSelected + (adjacentValue * 2)] == empty) {
    if (isSpaceAlreadyInArray(buttonSelected + adjacentValue * 2, i) == false) {

      RemoveTiles.push(buttonSelected + adjacentValue);

      let tile = new jumpTile(buttonSelected + (adjacentValue * 2));

      RemoveTiles.push(buttonSelected + adjacentValue);
      console.log("removeTiles" + RemoveTiles);

      for (let k = 0; k < RemoveTiles.length; k++) {
        tile.tilesToRemove.push(RemoveTiles[k]);
      }
      console.log("tile.tilesToRemove: " + tile.tilesToRemove);
      availableSpaces[i].push(tile);



      checkForJump(buttonSelected + (adjacentValue * 2), RemoveTiles,false);
      console.log("available spaces = " + availableSpaces);
    }
  }


}


   };


   function isSpaceAlreadyInArray(spot, arrayIndex) {
let SpaceAlreadyInArray = false;

for (let j = 0; j < availableSpaces[arrayIndex].length; j++) {
  if (availableSpaces[arrayIndex][j].tileID == spot) {
    SpaceAlreadyInArray = true;
  }
}
return SpaceAlreadyInArray;
  }


    function clearAvailableMoves() {
for (let i = 0; i < availableSpaces.length; i++) {



  availableSpaces[i].pop();


    }

  }



    function remove(removeList, button) {


for (let i = 0; i < removeList.length; i++) {
  board.value[removeList[i]] = empty;
  board.buttons[removeList[i]].textContent = empty;

  if (piece == black) {
    numBlackPieces--;
    checkForWin(numBlackPieces);
  } else if (piece == white) {
    numWhitePieces--;
    checkForWin(numWhitePieces);
  }

}
 clearAvailableMoves();
    };
```